# Is there a way to integrate my Google Drive with Google Music?

Tags: google-drive, google-play-music

Is there a way to integrate music files from my Google Drive with Google Music?

If not, are there any plans to add this functionality? I upload a lot of my files to Google Drive and it would be convenient to be able to play my music files from there, or even import them from there into Google Music.

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Music Player for Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/music-player-for-google-d/hnfeekfpnjbdmelcapngdgkjnhgijjkh?hl=en) and you can play all your music files from there.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Groove Music with Microsoft OneDrive - That setup works just like that. It's the only cloud music service that lets you play back your own actual files without matching algorithms that regularly fail. It does that by playing back files from your OneDrive music folder. You can, if you like, combine this with a Groove Music pass subscription for a Spotify like experience integrated with your own purchased music library. It puts Google Play, Apple Music and Amazon (the worst of the bunch by far) to shame. (I spent a 3 month period trialing all of the music services looking for the right fit / mix of subscription and playback of my own stuff). I have a vast library built up over 25 years or so and I signed up for an Office365 subscription that came with 1TB of OneDrive storage rolled in. Individual is about £60 and Family is £80 (5 users - 1TB each)

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote? Granted it's using an alternative product but, given the alternative answer is 'NO!' I'd consider that valid option.

Comment: Not sure about the reasons that specific downvoter had for downvoting, but I can give you reasons why I might do it: OP got in their question: *I upload a lot of my files to Google Drive and it would be convenient to be able to play my music files from there* and @Vembu 's answer provided a way to do exactly that. So it's clearly not true that there was *NO* alternative solution to the convoluted workaround you provided in your answer. Also the lack of formatting and too many extra details make your answer difficult to read.